# Dependencies not downloaded in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am creating a Spring Starter Project using Spring Tool Suite. I selected JPA, Web and Derby Database dependencies. When my new project is created the `src` folder displays a "?" mark as shown in the screenshot. What am I missing? Why the question mark?

[image]

Comment: Maybe your STS does not have access to the Internet, in this case you should configure a proxy for your IDE. The other way, define the dependencies in pom.xml and download with maven.

Answer (score 3):

Note that there's an entry called "Maven Dependencies" right above those folders. Maven doesn't download dependencies *into* your project, it puts them in your local repository (generally `~/.m2/repository`).

The question marks have nothing to do with dependencies--they're Eclipse's indication that you haven't added those entries to source control. (Contrast with the `mvnw` and POM entries, which have a stylized disk pack to show they are in source control.)